# CATransition type rippleEffect was disabled on iOS13

Tags: ios, ios13

Does anyone know some solution ？
I use this effect more than 4 years

Answer (score 0):

@SuperLiang

"RippleEffect" is an un-documented catransition types that was removed in ios13.
Please refer the available / supported catransition types in the below specified link.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catransition/common_transition_types